# mySQL PHP UPDATE file location getting three

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Okay I have a mysql php UPDATE which goes as follows:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='uploads/.$fn'
WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");
```

it updates imagelocation with the following: uploads/...

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: what is your final sql like, George?

Comment: sorry i don't understand?

Comment: I imagine you are getting some syntax error, that's why I've asked you for the output of your SQL. Anyway, Did work Dipesh's solution?

Comment: Dipesh's returned the same result. I'm going to try Sean's solution.

Comment: Could you george print out your sql. To do so, just write <?php echo "UPDATE users SET imagelocation='uploads/.$fn'
WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'"; ?> and tell me what is on your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are correction to made as below,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='uploads/".$fn."'
WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

First correction is `imagelocation='uploads/".$fn."'`.

Second Correction is `username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");`

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='uploads/$fn'
             WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'")
             or die(mysql_error());
```

When using php vars inside double quotes you don't need to concat with `.` and array values need to be surrounded by curly brackets `{}`

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't write anything to the database.

Comment: have you tried checking if there is errors - `mysql_error()`? Try `mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagelocation='uploads/$fn' WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());`